# Explicity Registering NuGet DLL's with Dependency

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, nuget-spec

My nuspec file uses both managed and unmanaged DLL's.  The following example works correctly and creates a project reference to managedDLL.dll...

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" />
</dependencies>
<references>
    <reference file="managedDLL.dll" />             
</references>
</metadata>
<files>
    <file src="..\managedDLL.dll" target="lib\net45\managedDLL.dll" /> 
    <file src="..\unManaged.dll" target="lib\net45\" />     
    <file src="VsDataHub.targets"  target="build" />
</files>
```

However, since I'm explicity defining which DLL's are managed (in references), a **project reference is no longer being created to the Newtonsoft.Json.dll installed via the dependency**.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where do managed and unmamaged dll's come from? Are they generated by your solution or are they external to your to your project? In the second case you could package them into a separate package and install it to your project, everything should then work fine. In my cases if nothing else helped i just used original NuGet sourcecode and debugged my current usecases with it.

Comment: The unmanaged dll's are third-party.

Comment: The third-party setup is similar to this...
DLL A (managed) 
        uses DLL B (unmanaged),
DLL C (managed)
        uses DLL D (unmanaged)